# SWT Overlay layout

Tags: swt, overlay

I want to have a transparent canvas.

I have a canvas in which video is getting rendered. I want a canvas on top of the video so that I can draw a rectangle over the video to select an area of the video for some other purpose (like to zoom, to take image etc...).

Is it possible in SWT?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some code so I can give it a swing?

Comment: I would like to know how to do this too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can have a transparent canvas, however you can implement double buffering on the canvas playing video, which would also improve frame rate and reduce screen flicker.

```
Image bufferImage = (Image) canvas.getData("buffer-image");
            Display display = Display.getDefault();
            if (bufferImage == null //if there is no image
                    || bufferImage.getBounds().width != canvas.getSize().x //if the image is incorrectly sized, which could result in unnecessary expenditures or not drawing everything
                    || bufferImage.getBounds().height != canvas.getSize().y) {
                bufferImage = new Image(display, canvas.getSize().x, canvas.getSize().y);
                canvas.setData("buffer-image", bufferImage);
            }

            GC bufferImageGC = new GC(bufferImage);
            bufferImageGC.setBackground(e.gc.getBackground());
            bufferImageGC.setForeground(e.gc.getForeground());

                    //fill in the background
            Rectangle background = bufferImage.getBounds();
            bufferImageGC.fillRectangle(0, 0, background.width, background.height);

                    //draw video here, remember to draw onto bufferImageGC
                    //draw anything else you want here
```

I hope this helps.